# How to get the grid coordinates of an element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-grid

Let's say I have a 3-column CSS-Grid. Is there a way, using JavaScript, to get the `grid-row` and `grid-column` of an auto-placed element?

Example:

```js
console.log($('#test').css('grid-row'), $('#test').css('grid-column'));
// expected output: 2 3 
// actual output: two empty strings
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle of the example: https://jsfiddle.net/w4u87d2f/7/

In this example I could figure it out by counting the elements and knowing the grid has three columns:

```
grid-column = $('#test').index() % 3 + 1;
grid-row = Math.ceil( $('#test').index() / 3 )
```

But that only works for very simple grids and also means I have to consider breakpoints that change the number of columns.

Edit: This is not a duplicate of [Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element), as I'm not interested in pixel coordinates but the row and column number within the CSS-Grid.

Comment: How would you handle mobile?

Comment: Why not just put that into the `id` and make life easy?

Comment: @RyanWilson I have added a fiddle that shows the example with a bit of added CSS to give the divs dimensions and colour.

Comment: @JayGould because in the task I'm trying to solve I don't have an `id` and the row number will be depended on the breakpoint.

Comment: @Rainb I'm not sure what you mean, how would I handle what on mobile?

Comment: @Seraphithan Will there always be a parent container div with class = grid? Also, in your example you are using JQuery, if an answer can utilize JQuery, please add that as a tag to your post.

Comment: @RyanWilson yes the parent will always have the class grid. And thanks for the tag advice.

Comment: @Seraphithan I think I may have a solution for you, I will post it as an answer. How will you be identifying the elements position inside the div with class = grid, will it get a class attribute added when clicking it, or what is the workflow for that??

Comment: @Seraphithan  In other words, how will you know which div inside div = grid you are targeting and wanting to know its position?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find in which column a CSS grid layout element is placed using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870156/how-to-find-in-which-column-a-css-grid-layout-element-is-placed-using-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
//Add click event for any child div of div = grid
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.grid').on('click', 'div', function(e){
          GetGridElementsPosition($(this).index()); //Pass in the index of the clicked div
    //Relevant to its siblings, in other words if this is the 5th div in the div = grid
    });
});

function GetGridElementsPosition(index){
    //Get the css attribute grid-template-columns from the css of class grid
    //split on whitespace and get the length, this will give you how many columns
    const colCount = $('.grid').css('grid-template-columns').split(' ').length;

    const rowPosition = Math.floor(index / colCount);
    const colPosition = index % colCount;

    //Return an object with properties row and column
    return { row: rowPosition, column: colPosition } ;
}
```

Comment: @Seraphithan If this isn't what you are looking for, let me know and I'll remove this.

Comment: This looks great, thanks and I think I can even adapt it to work with IE 11 grid. Hopefully there will be a direct way to access these parameters eventually, because I think this would break if an element spanned more than one row or column, but luckily that's not an issue with my task.

Comment: @seraphithan yeah, if an element can span multiple columns or rows, I'd have to see an example and it may be possible to modify this, glad it helps you.

Answer (score 10):

The above answer is a great start, and uses jQuery. Here is a pure Javascript equivalent, and also implements an "offset" in case you have specified the first child element's grid column (such as in a calendar where you specify the first day of the month)

```
function getGridElementsPosition(index) {
  const gridEl = document.getElementById("grid");

  // our indexes are zero-based but gridColumns are 1-based, so subtract 1
  let offset = Number(window.getComputedStyle(gridEl.children[0]).gridColumnStart) - 1; 

  // if we haven't specified the first child's grid column, then there is no offset
  if (isNaN(offset)) {
    offset = 0;
  }
  const colCount = window.getComputedStyle(gridEl).gridTemplateColumns.split(" ").length;

  const rowPosition = Math.floor((index + offset) / colCount);
  const colPosition = (index + offset) % colCount;

  //Return an object with properties row and column
  return { row: rowPosition, column: colPosition };
}

function getNodeIndex(elm) {
  var c = elm.parentNode.children,
    i = 0;
  for (; i < c.length; i++) if (c[i] == elm) return i;
}

function addClickEventsToGridItems() {
  let gridItems = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-item");
  for (let i = 0; i < gridItems.length; i++) {
    gridItems[i].onclick = (e) => {
      let position = getGridElementsPosition(getNodeIndex(e.target));
      console.log(`Node position is row ${position.row}, column ${position.column}`);
    };
  }
}

addClickEventsToGridItems();
```

Here is a [corresponding Pen](https://codepen.io/sorrellio/pen/jOqmZdq) that shows it in action on a calendar with a specified offset.

Comment: Thank you for the pure JS version. Didn't know about `window.getComputedStyle()` before and it really is a game changer here.

Comment: Great ideas here. Wondering how i can reactify this if columns and rows are built in React.

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution taking into considerations columns spans

```
function getGridPosition(elem) {
    var gridContainer = elem.parent();
    var simpleEl = elem.get(0);
    var gridItems = gridContainer.children('div');
    const colCount = $(gridContainer).css('grid-template-columns').split(' ').length;

    var row = 0;
    var col = 0;

    gridItems.each(function(index,el) {

        var item = $(el);
        if(simpleEl==el) {
            //console.log("FOUND!")
            return false;
        }
        var gridCols  = item.css("grid-column");
        if(gridCols != undefined && gridCols.indexOf("span")>=0){
            var gridColumnParts = gridCols.split('/');
            var spanValue = parseInt(gridColumnParts[0].trim().split(' ')[1], 10);
            //console.log("spanValue: " + spanValue);
            col = col+spanValue;
        }else{
            col++;
        }
        if(col>=colCount){
            col=0;
            row++;
        }
    });

    return {
        row: row,
        col: col
    };
}
```