# How to get grid coordinates which has some empty cells in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a grid that its some cells do not have an element. Some cells are empty. It asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51327802/how-to-get-the-grid-coordinates-of-an-element-using-javascript) but not working for the grid that has some empty cells My code example is below. How to get the position of an element on clicking?

```css
#GridContainer {
  width: 65vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 8vh auto 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.column1 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
.item {
  background-color: red;
}
.column0 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="GridContainer">
      <div class="item row1 column1"></div>
      <div class="item row1 column2"></div>
      <div class="item row1 column3"></div>
      <div class="item row2 column0"></div>
      <div class="item row2 column1"></div>
      <div class="item row2 column2"></div>
      <div class="item row2 column3"></div>
      <div class="item row3 column1"></div>
      <div class="item row3 column2"></div>
      <div class="item row3 column3"></div>
      <div class="item row3 column4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take a look at your code snippet: is the example as you intend? It seems as if you are missing classes `column2`, `column3` etc., resulting in a distorted view. You have a better chance of getting valuable answers if your example is representative of your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet parses the computed styles of the grid container to determine the amount and size of the rows and columns. It creates two arrays of top left row and column positions.

It then checks for a given element if the `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` of a given element is within the coordinates of each row and column. With it it determines the position on the grid.

It returns an object with the `row`, `column`, `x` and `y` values. All values are in relation to the grid element.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('GridContainer');

const getPositionInGrid = (element, grid) => {
  const gridStyles = getComputedStyle(grid);
  const display = gridStyles.getPropertyValue('display');
  if (display !== 'grid') {
    throw new Error('grid element does not have display value of grid;');
  }

  const rows = gridStyles.getPropertyValue('grid-template-rows').split(' ');
  const columns = gridStyles.getPropertyValue('grid-template-columns').split(' ');
  const gap = parseInt(gridStyles.getPropertyValue('grid-gap'));

  const rowPositions = rows.map((row, i) => {
    const rowPosition = parseInt(row);
    return !i ? 0 : (rowPosition + gap) * i;
  });

  const columnPositions = columns.map((column, i) => {
    const columnPosition = parseInt(column);
    return !i ? 0 : (columnPosition + gap) * i;
  });

  const {
    offsetTop,
    offsetLeft
  } = element;

  let row = null;
  rowPositions.forEach((position, i) => {
    const nextRow = rowPositions[i + 1];
    if ((!nextRow && row === null) || (offsetTop >= position && offsetTop < nextRow)) {
      row = i + 1;
    }
  });

  let column = null;
  columnPositions.forEach((position, i) => {
    const nextColumn = columnPositions[i + 1];
    if ((!nextColumn && column === null) || (offsetLeft >= position && offsetLeft < nextColumn)) {
      column = i + 1;
    }
  });

  return { row, column, y: offsetTop, x: offsetLeft};
};

container.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const {
    target
  } = event;
  if (target.classList.contains('item')) {
    const {
      row, 
      column,
      x,
      y
    } = getPositionInGrid(target, container);
    console.log('Row:', `${row},`, 'Column:', column, '|', 'x:', `${x},`, 'y:', y);
  }
});
```

```css
#GridContainer {
  width: 65vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 8vh auto 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.column1 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.item {
  background-color: red;
}

.column0 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="GridContainer">
  <div class="item row1 column1"></div>
  <div class="item row1 column2"></div>
  <div class="item row1 column3"></div>
  <div class="item row2 column0"></div>
  <div class="item row2 column1"></div>
  <div class="item row2 column2"></div>
  <div class="item row2 column3"></div>
  <div class="item row3 column1"></div>
  <div class="item row3 column2"></div>
  <div class="item row3 column3"></div>
  <div class="item row3 column4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this layout instead:

```html
<div id="grid-container">
  <div class="column column-0">
    <div class="row row-0"></div>
    <div class="row row-1 row-empty"></div>
    <div class="row row-2"></div>
    <div class="row row-3"></div>
    <div class="row row-4 row-empty"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column-1">
    <div class="row row-0"></div>
    <div class="row row-1"></div>
    <div class="row row-2 row-empty"></div>
    <div class="row row-3"></div>
    <div class="row row-4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column-2">
    <div class="row row-0"></div>
    <div class="row row-1"></div>
    <div class="row row-2 row-empty"></div>
    <div class="row row-3"></div>
    <div class="row row-4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column-3">
    <div class="row row-0 row-empty"></div>
    <div class="row row-1"></div>
    <div class="row row-2"></div>
    <div class="row row-3 row-empty"></div>
    <div class="row row-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can easily loop through your grid columns and rows and get 2D array of empty elements.

You can use some styles for your empty items as well to avoid some king of disorted view and keep your table cells size:

```css
.row-empty {
  opacity: 0; // Now you can't see this element
  pointer-events: none; // Now you can't click on it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you assume when talking about the position. Here is my possible solution where I work with two different variants.

```js
function handleClickedCell(cell) {
    // To get the position in terms of classes.
    // E.g., [ "item", "row1", "column1" ].
    console.log(Array.from(cell.classList));

    // To get the position in terms of pixels.
    /* E.g.,
     * {
     *     "x": 184.23333740234375,
     *     "y": 41.91667175292969,
     *     "width": 69.66665649414062,
     *     "height": 133.06666564941406,
     *     "top": 41.91667175292969,
     *     "right": 253.89999389648438,
     *     "bottom": 174.98333740234375,
     *     "left": 184.23333740234375
     * }
     */
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cell.getBoundingClientRect()));

    // Other necessary actions.
}

document
    .getElementById('GridContainer')
    .addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        handleClickedCell(event.target);
    });
```

```css
#GridContainer {
  width: 65vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 8vh auto 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.column1 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
.item {
  background-color: red;
}
.column0 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="GridContainer">
      <div class="item row1 column1"></div>
      <div class="item row1 column2"></div>
      <div class="item row1 column3"></div>
      <div class="item row2 column0"></div>
      <div class="item row2 column1"></div>
      <div class="item row2 column2"></div>
      <div class="item row2 column3"></div>
      <div class="item row3 column1"></div>
      <div class="item row3 column2"></div>
      <div class="item row3 column3"></div>
      <div class="item row3 column4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Terbiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2008562/terbiy) answer is good. However empty cells are clickable and he added eventlistener to grid not children of grid. The following code is what I want exactly. Remember that column and row number start 0 because first column offsetLeft is equal to
grid offsetLeft and first row offsetTop is equal to grid offsetTop

```js
 function getPosition(el) {
        var xPos = 0
        var yPos = 0
        while (el) {
          if (el.tagName === 'BODY') {
            // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
            var xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft
            var yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop

            xPos += el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft
            yPos += el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop
          } else {
            // for all other non-BODY elements
            xPos += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft
            yPos += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop
          }

          el = el.offsetParent
        }
        return {
          x: xPos,
          y: yPos,
        }
      }
      function getSquareDimensions() {
        const grid = document.getElementById('GridContainer')
        const gridPosition = getPosition(grid)
        const rowCount = 3 //row count in grid
        const columnCount = 5 //column count in grid

        const width = grid.offsetWidth / columnCount
        const height = grid.offsetHeight / rowCount

        return { width, height }
      }
      function getGridElementPosition(element, gridId) {
        const grid = document.getElementById(gridId)
        const gridPosition = getPosition(grid)
        console.log('grid position')
        console.log(gridPosition)
        const elementPosition = getPosition(element)
        console.log('element position')
        console.log(elementPosition)
        const x = elementPosition.x - gridPosition.x
        const y = elementPosition.y - gridPosition.y
        const { width, height } = getSquareDimensions()

      
        const column = Math.round(x / width)
        const row = Math.round(y / height)

        return { row, column }
      }

      const grid = document.getElementById('GridContainer')

      for (const child of grid.children) {
        child.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          console.log(getGridElementPosition(e.target, 'GridContainer'))
        })
      }
```

```css
#GridContainer {
  width: 65vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 8vh auto 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.column1 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
.item {
  background-color: red;
}
.column0 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="GridContainer">
      <div class="item row0 column1"></div>
      <div class="item row0 column2"></div>
      <div class="item row0 column3"></div>
      <div class="item row1 column0"></div>
      <div class="item row1 column1"></div>
      <div class="item row1 column2"></div>
      <div class="item row1 column3"></div>
      <div class="item row2 column1"></div>
      <div class="item row2 column2"></div>
      <div class="item row2 column3"></div>
      <div class="item row2 column4"></div>
</div>
```